# Create .ics file with javascript

Tags: javascript, icalendar

I have to create a .ics file with Javascript. I haven't got the possibility to use jquery. 
Is there a way to create this file? 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

```html
const downloadICalFile = (content: string, fileName: string) => {
    const blob = new Blob([content], { type: 'text/calendar;charset=utf-8' });
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    a.download = fileName;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [one of the methods described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file) to write a file in Javascript, then the content of the .ics file is up to you to determine. It's quite trivial since the [ics format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) is simple. ([complete RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545))

Comment: As I read it I have to use jquery. This isn't possible. So it isn't possible only to use JS?

Comment: If you can use PHP, I suggest you to generate the ics in a PHP page, then link to this page with javasript (or directly in HTML)